# Display an image from a model object in Django

Tags: django

So I have this model:

```
class Inssurance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    logo = models.FileField(blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this one:

```
class Folder(models.Model): #Dossiers sinistre
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=dossier_number, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Prestataire, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    matricule = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XXXXX-A-1")
    Inssurance= models.ForeignKey(Inssurance, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

And I am working on the Folder's template and I want to display the image of the related Inssurance.

This is what I came up with but the image does not get displayed:

```
<img src="{{folder.inssurance.logo.url}}" alt=""/>
```

This is what I found when I run the server:
The image is not found, and when I right-click on it and click on View Image, it gives me a 404 error, even though when I check in my server, I find the image uploaded.

There are my media settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor correction has to be done in Folder model.
Field name

```
Inssurance =
```

but in your template

```
folder.inssurance.logo.url
```

change it to

```
folder.Inssurance.logo.url
```

Comment: First of all, Inssurance =  and Inssurance= is the same thing, it's not a problem in coding, and I have it Inssurance = in my code.Second of all, folder.inssurance (that's accessing the variable), folder.Inssurance, throws an error because you are trying to access an object.

Comment: I mean ''I'' capital in Inssurance. you are calling wrong variable. It is case sensitive

Comment: Oh, no I made the mistake in stackoverflow, in the code it's i not I.